# How do I use existing raw java code in a new Netbeans GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

I have some existing hand written GUI code that I wrote in a text editor the hard way. It eventually compiled nicely but now I want to use the GUI builder in NetBeans v7.3 to make some extensive improvements. I cannot for the life of me find any information on how I can load/interface my .java file into the NetBeans IDE GUI Builder. Can anyone steer me to a solution or maybe suggest some keywords? Thanks...

Comment: I doubt GUI builders will be compatible with hand written GUI code, since GUI builders auto-generate their code.

Comment: You can add your existing, hand coded, components to NetBeans forms, but you won't be able to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Project in **NetBeans** then Copy those **.Java** files into your Package. MAke Sure PAckage name is Correct. Now you can run the GUI from NEtbeans without any Issue. But If you want to use the Designer Mode of **Netbeans** you need to Create the **JFRAME** from Netbeans toolbox. Else all there will not be any Issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have prewritten GUI code that wasn't generated using NetBeans, it's practically impossible to edit it using NetBean's view editor. With that said, you have a couple options. If you designed your application using an MVC approach, then mocking up another view isn't too bad given that your controller and model are independent of the view (for the most part). If your GUI is pretty complex, then I would suggest continuing the project by hand. The GUI builder doesn't really have any benefits other than allowing the developer the ability to mock up designs in a faster manner.